# less than operator is not guaranteeing uniqueness for set of objects

Tags: c++, object, set, operator-overloading

I am trying to construct a set of objects called guests. For this purpose, I overloaded the less than operator. The problem is that I'm not getting unique elements. I can't figure out why. The size of the set is always 2 in the following example.

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

class Guest{
    public:
     Guest(const std::string &fn, const std::string &ln, const std::string &em, const std::string &loy):firstname(fn), lastname(ln), email(em),loyalty(loy){}

     std::string firstname;
     std::string lastname;
     std::string email;
     std::string loyalty;
    
};

bool operator<(const Guest& l, const Guest& r){
    return (l.firstname < r.firstname) or ((l.firstname == r.firstname) and
           ((l.lastname < r.lastname) or ((l.lastname == r.lastname) and
           ((l.email < r.email) or ((l.email == r.email) and
           ((l.loyalty < r.loyalty) or ((l.loyalty == r.loyalty))))))));
}

int main() {
    Guest g1("g1","g2","g3","g4");
    Guest g2("g1","g2","g3","g4");
    
    std::set<Guest> guests = {g1,g2};
    std::cout << guests.size() << std::endl; //Size is always 2 in here. It should be 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `operator<` actually behaves like `<=`. Or ask yourself wether you really want `g1 < g1` to be true or not. An object can never be less than itself.

Comment: Well, if you actually work out your logic, or try out your comparison, you will discover that both `g1 < g2` is true, and `g2 < g1` is true as well. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

Comment: God Bless Mr. Spock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the last part `or ((l.loyalty == r.loyalty))`, otherwise the `operator<` would return `true` when all the data members of `Guest` are equivalent.

```
bool operator<(const Guest& l, const Guest& r){
    return (l.firstname < r.firstname) or ((l.firstname == r.firstname) and
           ((l.lastname < r.lastname) or ((l.lastname == r.lastname) and
           ((l.email < r.email) or ((l.email == r.email) and
           ((l.loyalty < r.loyalty) ))))));
}
```

Or make it much simpler with `std::tie`.

```
bool operator<(const Guest& l, const Guest& r){
    return std::tie(l.firstname, l.lastname, l.email, l.loyalty) < 
           std::tie(r.firstname, r.lastname, r.email, r.loyalty);
}
```